# Where to put log4j.properties into Maven project in Eclipse having some "default package" inside "src"-folder?

Tags: java, log4j

I a new user of Eclipse. I put log4j.properties into src-folder. For some reason my src-folder has "default package" and I don't know how to put log4j.properties inside of it.
As a consiquence, I have this kind of exception:

```
log4j:ERROR Could not read configuration file [log4j.properties].
java.io.FileNotFoundException: log4j.properties (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:372)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.configure(PropertyConfigurator.java:403)
    at HelloWorld.main(HelloWorld.java:9)
log4j:ERROR Ignoring configuration file [log4j.properties].
```

Moving log4j.properties into src/main/resources does not solve the prolem.

Here is my code:

import org.apache.log4j.Logger; 
import org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator;

public class HelloWorld {

```
static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(HelloWorld.class);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    PropertyConfigurator.configure("log4j.properties");
    logger.debug("Sample debug message");
    logger.info("Sample info message");
    logger.warn("Sample warn message");
    logger.error("Sample error message");
    logger.fatal("Sample fatal message");
}
```

}

log4j.properties file:

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file, errorfile

# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender

#Redirect to Tomcat logs folder
#log4j.appender.file.File=${catalina.home}/logs/logging.log

log4j.appender.file.File=C:\\log\\logging.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n


log4j.appender.errorfile=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.errorfile.Threshold=ERROR
log4j.appender.errorfile.File=C:\\log\\errorlogging.log
log4j.appender.errorfile.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.errorfile.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.errorfile.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.errorfile.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

You have to add the log4j.properties file in the following location.

For main code base -> **src/main/resources**

For test code base -> **src/test/resources**

Besides, if you are using Maven, add the below code in pom.xml in the build section.

```
<resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <targetPath>${project.build.directory}</targetPath>
            <includes>
                <include>log4j.properties</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
```

After doing all the above, refresh the project in Eclipse. Build the maven project with the command `mvn clean package` or `mvn clean install`. Inside the project, you should be able to see the log4j.properties file inside build/classes directory.

Answer (score 0):

O must put on src/main/resources folder.

https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html